# Is there an Apache solr filter for path?

Tags: search

Is there a way to filter results by path with Apache Solr?

For instance, we would like have a filter that limits results to "/my-path-here".

It would only return results that have a path that begins with that.

- /my-path-here/one
- /my-path-here/nested/link
- /my-other-path/should-not-show-in-results

Comment: Is this really about Drupal? Would your question be any different if pathes were generated and sent to Solr by any other web app?

Comment: Yes were using Drupal to integrate with it so any answer would hopefully be within the context of Drupal.